# How to invoke a controller using a html link in Spring-mvc?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp page called reports.jsp and I have displayed the links in the view for a user to click.
How can I invoke Spring controller method by clicking on the link that will pass an argument.

Comment: What does the link look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `@PathVariable` in order to do this. Example:

Jsp:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/test/${object.argument}" />" >hello</a>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/{argument}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Controller(@PathVariable("argument") String argument) {
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the answer by creating a link:

```
<a href=".../test?argName=arg1" >hello</a>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"argName"})
    public String Controller(@RequestParam(value="argName", required = true, defaultValue = null) String argName) {
       ...
       //Now do exciting things with variable argName
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**On the JSP page**

```
<a class="opcion"  href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/inicio">Inicio</a>
```

**And in the controller part backend**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/inicio", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "cargaGeneracion");
        return "index";
    }
}
```