# How to invoke a controller using anchor tag in Spring-mvc?

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, anchor

I want to invoke backend controller while anchor tag is clicked.
I still want user to be taken to the url, but I need to perform some other logic in the code.

```
<a href="<c:out value="${url}"/><c:out value="${name}"/><c:out value="${url}"/>"><c:out value="${name}"/></a>
```

This question is very similar to [How to invoke a controller using a html link in Spring-mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403672/how-to-invoke-a-controller-using-a-html-link-in-spring-mvc)
But unfortunately, the answers in that question doesn't apply to my case. I don't want to change the href value.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you could do by javascript and ajax, intercept the anchor click event, make the call to the controller, and with the response, do whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<a id="btnClick">click me</a>
    <script>
        $('#btnClick').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url : yourUrlToController
                //todo something like that
            });
        });
    </script>
```